# Reverse Engineering: Results per page on arrow.com

Tags: url, curl, reverse-engineering

I am trying to increase the results per page for example when you open:
http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99

The website gives you the option to choose from displaying 10, 25, 50 or 100 by clicking on the link 50. Now My question is how I would display 99999 results with curl for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you're targeting, http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99, uses a form to supply POST data the server uses to identify how many records to return, what starting offset to use for pagination, how it should be sorted, etc.

As @EvanLarsen's noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738978/reverse-engineering-results-per-page-on-arrow-com/6782575#6782575), you need to use `curl -d "<POST_DATA>" <URL>`.

However, it appears the site will properly respond to a request with only those fields you actually care about supplied.

To return only the first record:

```
curl -d "limit=1" http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99
```

To return only the second record:

```
curl -d "limit=1&start=1" http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99
```

To return 99999 records (as you asked):

```
curl -d "limit=99999" http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99
```

If you want a decent UI to make modifying and submitting POST data and viewing results easier in a web browser (instead of using `curl`), check out the [Request Maker Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kajfghlhfkcocafkcjlajldicbikpgnp?hl=en-US).

Comment: Neither `curl -d "limit=99999" http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99` nor using Request Maker Chrome Extension with `limit=99999` will give me back more than 10 results a page.

Comment: Apparently (based on my trial and error) they're restricting the results when limit is set any higher than 4000 and returning "No Search Results Found." But with `limit=4000` or below, it's returning all 143 results in this category for me.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com) to come up with the following HTTP request, which looks like it returns all 143 matching items one a single page.  I did this by watching the HTTP request that was sent when I selected "100 Results" from the drop-down. I then copied the raw request, pasted it into Fiddler2's RequestBuilder, changed the `limit=200`, and executed it. I compared the response in the WebView against the actual pages displayed on the website.

```
POST http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99 HTTP/1.1
Host: components.arrow.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99
Content-Length: 331
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://components.arrow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.122 Safari/534.30
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __utmz=199791230.1309618262.1.1.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/5359805/problem-while-parsing-html-xml-and-quering-with-xpath; __utma=199791230.901122760.1309618262.1309618262.1309618262.1; region=na; lang=en; JSESSIONID=s4CyTyHKHbwhJc2v1xXyv50s3mvshZmZJJzGYQNjpmHnw2MmcgyT!1070203391

sort1Name=&sort1Order=&start=0&docid=&cat=&filtMultiSelect=&catFiltAddOn=&chkButton=1&search_token=BAV99&limit=200&requestedURL=http%3A%2F%2Fext.partsearch.arrow.com%2Fnacpartservice%2Fsearch%3Fappid%3Dnac%26cc%3DUS%26cn%3DARROW%2FAMERICAS%26lang%3Den%26retfilt%3DY%26retreq%3DY%26srchtxt%3DBAV99%26start%3D0%26limit%3D10&taxonomy=
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
curl -d "sort1Name=&sort1Order=&start=0&docid=&cat=&filtMultiSelect=&catFiltAddOn=&chkButton=1&search_token=BAV99&limit=9999&requestedURL=http%3A%2F%2Fext.partsearch.arrow.com%2Fnacpartservice%2Fsearch%3Fappid%3Dnac%26cc%3DUS%26cn%3DARROW%2FAMERICAS%26lang%3Den%26retfilt%3DY%26retreq%3DY%26srchtxt%3DBAV99%26start%3D0%26limit%3D10&taxonomy=" http://components.arrow.com/part/search/BAV99
```

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished by using Chrome Developer tools (or Firebug):

[image]

But as others mentioned, the server is restricting this parameter, so you cannot send `9999`